# Javascript Form Validation with "z" && ( "x" || "y" )

Tags: javascript

Seem to be having a little trouble getting some validation to work.

Currently trying to implement a system that will redirect a user if a variable is false, AND a form contains 0000 or 1111.

Example:

```
if xml_response == "false" && form == ("0000" || "1111") {
    window.location.replace("");
} else {
    submit.form
}
```

I've been able to get it working for 0000. If XML generates false, and form contains 0000, successful redirection.

If XML generates false and form contains 1111, no dice. I'm thinking it has to do with how I'm formatting my operators. Any ideas?

Here's my statement:

```
if (response == "false" && document.forms['Form'].id.value==("0000" || "1111") ) {
window.location.replace("http://url/");
} else {
document.getElementById("submit_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: The expression `("0000" || "1111")` evaluates to `"0000"`. The `||` operator returns its left-hand side operand if it has a "truthy" value (a value that would be considered true in an `if` statement, for example), otherwise it returns the right-hand side operand.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's invalid, you have to check for each value individually

```
if ((xml_response == "false") && (form == "0000" || form == "1111")) {
    window.location.replace("");
} else {
    submit.form
}
```

Note that you're checking for the string false and strings that look like numbers.

There's also the option to check an array for multiple values

```
if ( 
    ( response == "false" ) && 
    ( ['0000','1111'].indexOf(document.forms['Form'].id.value) != -1 )
   ) 
{
   window.location.replace("http://url/");
} else {
   document.getElementById("submit_form").submit();
}
```

or even

```
/(0000|1111)/.exec(document.forms['Form'].id.value)
```

Comment: There's also `document.forms['Form'].id.value in {'0000':'','1111':''}` and `/0000|1111/.test(document.forms['Form'].id.value)`.

Comment: That did it. The array check is exactly what I was looking for. Tested and working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

```
document.forms['Form'].id.value
```

will attempt to find a form in the document with a name or ID of "Form". If it finds one, it will access it's ID property, which is a string, and attempt to read it's *value* property. Strings don't have a "value" property, so the result will be the value *undefined*.